# IE6 and 7 issue with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

IE6 and 7 issue with innerHTML

I have used ajax in the application i have develop, but there are issues with IE6 and IE7, they doesn't support innerHTML. What must be used to fixed this issue and to be a cross browser compatible?

the sample code looks like this.

```
function showFAQ(src, target){
     xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
       if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
         document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
       }
    }

    str = "?action=get&request="+src;
    xhr.open("GET", "./requests/data.php"+encodeURI(str), true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

In FireFox, IE8 and other major browsers works fine. Just the problem is with IE6 and 7.

Any help/advice will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: for cross-browser ajax, you can save yourself a lot of trouble and time by using an ajax(-capable) JS framework, like jQuery, Prototype look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks) .

Comment: I don't know about IE7, but for IE6 you have to use ActiveXObject. innerHTML works fine in IE6/7+, it is not your issue.

Comment: I use ActiveXObject for IE6, IE 7 supports XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Post the code initializing xhr.

Comment: IE6/7 do support `innerHTML` -- in fact Microsoft invented it (it was a proprietary feature in IE5 which was later added to other browsers and became part of the DOM standard) -- so your analysis of the problem as stated in the question is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var xmlHttp;

function getXmlHttpObject() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    try {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer 6+
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

var xhr = getXmlHttpObject();
```

---

**Update**

Try adding

```
xhr.send(null);
```

after

```
str = "?action=get&request="+src;
xhr.open("GET", "./requests/data.php"+encodeURI(str), true);
```

Comment: I have used this thing, but it doesn't work in IE6 and 7. innerHTML is not fully supported by Microsoft. You can check the post here : http://domscripting.com/blog/display/99

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @G_Coder: I presume you've tried `alert(xhr.responseText);` and seen if that part works before trying to use `.innerHTML` which you say isn't working in IE6/7? Either way, please try my update above.

Comment: I have tried but still no go. I'm so pissed of with this issue, so i use JQuery ajax and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

IE cannot update readonly elements using innerHTML... consider this too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML is supported as of IE5. I think you problem is the use of the xmlhttprequest object. That one is only supported as of IE7. You can however ActiveXObject as stealthyninja's code uses.