# When using ajax to get xml I can't use the xml object with jquery in ie6

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I use javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","./parts.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xml=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    alert(xml);
    var html = $(xml).find('part#partid').html();
    $('#content').html(html);

});
```

This seems to work in all other browsers but in IE I get this:
[image]

It says that the innerHTML is null or not an object but when I use `alert(xml)` it tells me that it is an object:

[image]

I'm trying to get it to work because my boss wants it to work in IE6. Someone has a clue on what's going on here an/or how to fix/ work around?

Comment: `xml` is not `whateverTheErrorIsAbout.innerHTML`.

Comment: Why are you even supporting IE6? Windows XP doesn't even get security updates any more and even it goes up to IE8.

Comment: For some stupid handheld devices with windows mobile - plz I know IE6 sucks but I need this to work in IE6

Comment: try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7572289/1385672